# Flutter sharedpreferences boolean always return true

Tags: flutter, dart, sharedpreferences, future

i am developing a flutter app. App has onboarding screen. I want to store that the user first open. I am using sharedpreferences for this. Below codes, always open OnBoardingScreen. Whats my fault ? please help me.

**save bool method**

```
saveBool(bool isOk) async { 
  final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  prefs.setBool('firstOpen', isOk);
}
```

**check bool method**

```
 checkFirstOpen() async {
  SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  bool checkValue = prefs.containsKey('firstOpen');
  return checkValue;
}
}
```

And here i decide to route

**main.dart**

```
home: checkFirstOpen() == true ? MyHomePage() : OnboardingScreen());
```

I save bool in setState.

```
onTap: (){
                var route = new MaterialPageRoute(
                          builder: (BuildContext context) =>
                              new MyHomePage(),
                        );
                        Navigator.of(context).push(route);
                        setState(() {
                          saveBool(true);
                        });
              },
```

Answer (score 0):

You are simply checking if you the key is present or not.
Remove this line

```
prefs.containsKey("firstOpen");
```

Instead, access the value using

```
prefs.getBool("firstOpen") ?? true
```

Comment: I changed to prefs.getBool("firstOpen"); but nothing changed.

Comment: May be you are saving true instead of false then. //saveBool(false)

Comment: You dont need to setState. And you are saving bool(true) do savebool(false)

Comment: same problem. my checkFirstOpen() method returns null first run.